# Angular 1 get range value

Tags: angularjs

Probably a super duper simple question, but I can't seem to hack it.
I'm using Ionic and trying to get the value a user has selected from a range.

```
<input type="range" ng-model="quantity" min="5" max="30" data-ng-init="quantity ? quantity = quantity : quantity = 25" >

    <div ng-click="getValue()">Get Value</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.getValue = function() {
    console.log($scope.quantity)
}
```

It returns "undefined" in console?

Many thanks!

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/fgc21e86/11/

Comment: Is this issue related - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1948?

Comment: Well maybe he isnt using angularJS v1.4.8

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with `data-ng-init`
Here is working version.

Demo https://plnkr.co/edit/wRYJfFgFZ8EMlxNUesy5?p=preview

Comment: Doesn't seem to want to work :/ must be an ionic thing. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. In Ionic—which I believe is a different method to Angular—it is not two-way binding, just "inheritance". So you need to make it a data object to get binding.

```
   <input type="range" name="volume" ng-model="q.quantity" ng-change="hold()" min="5" max="30" data-ng-init="q.quantity ? q.quantity = q.quantity : q.quantity = 25" >
```

Then `console.log($scope.q.quantity)` works.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/working-with-ng-model-and-input-type-range/949